# Disable table scrolling in jupyter cell

Tags: css, jupyter

I am currently using a library in `jupyter` notebook which generates a scrollable HTML table.
Is there any way to override scrollable settings for a cell (or the notebook)? I want to list the entire table without scrollability.

I see that the library has following style:

```
/* Make the table scrollable */
#meterstick-container {
 max-height: 700px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/meterstick/blob/master/confidence_interval_display_demo.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set custom CSS for the library from python code:

```
meterstick.confidence_interval_display.CSS = (
"""
#meterstick-container {
 max-height: 100% !important;
}
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the container full hight and see if it works :

```
#meterstick-container {
 max-height: 100vh !importnat;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I cant modify the library code due to certain restrictions. Can I add some css settings in jupyter cell which overrides it?